# CoreDNS subdomain resolution failing with hosts plugin

Tags: coredns

We are working on adding Coredns to our setup, and so far it's working fine. Currently we have DNS resolution working with hosts plugin where we are able to add a domain-name in hosts, and it resolves correctly.

But it's not resolving any subdomains correctly, since we want to resolve it to a private-IP via hosts plugin/or any other way.

Is there any workaround for this. We cannot add all the subdomains, since they are more than 100 of them and they keep changing.

Configmap:

```
In Yaml
  - name: hosts
    configBlock: |-
      10.XXX.XX.XX my-domain.com
      ttl 300
      reload 1m
      fallthrough
```

In the above case, it works for my-domain.com but doesn't work for subdomain.my-domain.com

In K8s:

```
      hosts {
        10.XXX.XX.XX my-domain.com
        ttl 300
        reload 1m
        fallthrough
    }
```

Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: I had this question also. I don't think it's possible without hardcoding the subdomains in some way. According to `hosts` plugin [docs](https://coredns.io/plugins/hosts/), the address mapping follows exactly the syntax you would use in `/etc/hosts` (see cited RFCs in the doc) which doesn't support any wildcards. I think your best bet would be to automate writing of an external hosts file and load that with the `hosts` plugin. You already have the `reload` directive in there.